# Column of Kendo Grid is not resizable in IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Grid in my web app and including kendo.all.min.js file. The version of this js file is 2012.1.515.
In the grid, columns are not resizeable in IE 10 and IE 11 though it works fine in all other browsers.

I have created a sample of grid and included the same file but grid columns are not resizeable in IE 10 and IE 11.
Here is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.dataviz.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="/kendo-ui/content/shared/styles/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

        <div id="main">
    <h1 id="exampleTitle">
            <span class="exampleIcon gridIcon"></span>
            <strong>Grid /</strong> Column resizing    </h1>

    <div id="theme-list-container"></div>

    <div id="exampleWrap">
        <script>preventFOUC()</script>


        <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                                        },
                                    });
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: gridDataSource,
                        scrollable: true,
                        resizable: true,

                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "OrderDate",
                                title: "Order Date"


                            },
                            {
                                field: "ShipCountry",
                                title: "Ship Country"

                            },
                            {
                                field: "ShipCity",
                                title: "Ship City"

                            },
                            {
                                field: "ShipName",
                                title: "Ship Name"

                            },
                            {
                                field: "ShippedDate",
                                title: "Shipped Date"

                            },
                            {
                                field: "OrderID",
                                title: "ID"

                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question over on Telerik's developer and support forums: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to specify width for every columns to resize. Something like:

```
    columns: [
    {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        width: 50px
    }
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: width should be same for all? because i am also facing the same issue for resizable not working with latest Kendo version :(

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with clicking in ie10 and 11. Telerik advised me to update my js and css with latest edition. Which eventually solved my problem. Try update your kendo version to something on 2013. They have 4/5 updates on 2013, go for 3/4th one.